# Pandas - moving average for date with many measurements per date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, rolling-computation

I have a DataFrame with date and sales. I want to calculate the moving average of the last 5 days and assign it to each day. The problem is that I have multiple measurements for each day (1115 to be precide - for single measurement I know how to do this).

My data looks like this:

```
    Date        Sales
0   2013-01-01  0
1   2013-01-01  0
2   2013-01-01  0
3   2013-01-01  0
4   2013-01-01  0
... ... ...
1017204 2015-07-31  9082
1017205 2015-07-31  10708
1017206 2015-07-31  7481
1017207 2015-07-31  10460
1017208 2015-07-31  5263
```

I wnat to first calculate the moving average for the last 5 days (taking average over all 1115 * 5 = 5575 measurements for the last 5 days), then assign it back to each single measurement (each measurement should have this average assigned). My data would then look like this:

```
    Date        Sales       Last5DaysAvg
0   2013-01-01  0   NaN
1   2013-01-01  0   NaN
2   2013-01-01  0   NaN
3   2013-01-01  0   NaN
4   2013-01-01  0   NaN
... ... ...
5576    2013-01-06  (average from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-06)
5577    2013-01-06  (average from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-06)
5578    2013-01-06  (average from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-06)
...
1017204 2015-07-31  9082    (average from 2015-07-26 to 2015-07-31)
1017205 2015-07-31  10708   (average from 2015-07-26 to 2015-07-31)
1017206 2015-07-31  7481    (average from 2015-07-26 to 2015-07-31)
1017207 2015-07-31  10460   (average from 2015-07-26 to 2015-07-31)
1017208 2015-07-31  5263    (average from 2015-07-26 to 2015-07-31)
```

I tried using the `.count()` aggregate for starters, since it's easy to verify - it should return 5575 in each row (except for the first 5575 rows, where of course I'll have NaNs):

```
df = df.rolling("5D", on="Date").count()
```

But I get:

```
    Date        Sales
0   2013-01-01  1.0
1   2013-01-01  2.0
2   2013-01-01  3.0
3   2013-01-01  4.0
4   2013-01-01  5.0
... ... ...
1017204 2015-07-31  5571.0
1017205 2015-07-31  5572.0
1017206 2015-07-31  5573.0
```

So it looks like it took each day separately and didn't calculate the moving window at all.

**Question:** how can I achieve the result outlined above?

**Data:** (first 30000 rows) https://pastebin.com/5bQ4Zt3f

**EDIT:** I managed to get this working, but in quite ugly way, I think there is prettier and more effective way. Also the code below has hard-coded number of measurements per day, which is something that couldn't be always guaranteed.

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="D")]) \
             .sum() \
             .reset_index() \
             .sort_values("Date")
df = df.rolling(5, on="Date").sum()
df["Sales"] = df["Sales"] / (1115 * 5)
```

```
Date    Sales
0   2013-01-01  NaN
1   2013-01-02  NaN
2   2013-01-03  NaN
3   2013-01-04  NaN
4   2013-01-05  4661.063857
... ... ...
937 2015-07-27  5435.554439
938 2015-07-28  5871.071031
939 2015-07-29  6211.633722
940 2015-07-30  6709.784036
941 2015-07-31  8471.914439
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you have multiple rows for each date. I see 2 possible interpretations:

- Either these are values you have to aggregate at the star and then produce a single rolling average:

```py
df.groupBy('Date').sum().rolling(5).mean().reset_index()
```

- Or these are different products - then you still have to group by but instead of aggregating you can compute the rolling average for each product:

```py
df.groupby('Product')['Date'].rolling(5).mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the bit about the "Product" column - I don't have it (just index, Date and Sales), what should I do? The index is already the default one, so reset_index() doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Edited, let me know if this needs further clarifying

Comment: Clarification from my side - I have 1115 stores, so 1115 sales values per each day, so I just need 1 rolling average (it represents the trend in the data). For this reason I wanted to avoid calculating sum/average for each day with groupby(). Instead, I think it would be more proper to just take values from last 5 days (from all stores, so 1115 * 5 values) and calculate the mean directly from those.

Comment: I am not sure if you would gain anything by avoiding the initial aggregation - this reduces the complexity of all your following manipulations. But you could simply roll by `1115*5` rows instead and then pick the first value for each date i.e. `df.rolling(1115*5).mean().groupby('Date').first().reset_index()`

Comment: You're probably right, I may be overthinking this. Thank for help!